# Automapper threw exception while mapping

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, model-view-controller, automapper

I need to map Dto model into view model but automapper threw an exeption while maps custom field. An error is as follows:

```
Frontend.Test.MappingTest.TestAutoMapperMapping threw exception: 
AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: The following property on     System.Int32 cannot be mapped: Id
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type System.Int32.
Context:
    Mapping to property Id from Shared.Common.Service.Model.Metadata.FieldDto`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to System.Int32
Mapping from type Common.Service.Model.Dto to BBR.Frontend.Models.ViewModel
```

My classes looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Dto
{
    [DataMember]
    public FieldDto<int> Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public FieldDto<string> Name { get; set; }
}


 public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And Mapper:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Dto, ViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>  src.Id.Value))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name.Value)).ReverseMap();
```

Any ideas how to handle it?

FieldDto:

```
[DataContract]
public class FieldDto<TValue>
{
    [DataMember]
    public TValue Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int UserRights { get; set; } = 3;

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I call ViewModel like this:

```
return View(Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(obj));
```

Comment: Consider posting the code that raises this exception

Comment: Post code of Common.Service.Model.Dto and BBR.Frontend.Models.ViewModel. Also it would be nice to see your mapping configuration. It looks like your Id property in Dto object does not have integer type

Comment: Ive added relevant classes for models and mapper

Comment: It should work. Show also `FieldDto` class and `Mapper.Map` call.

Comment: return View(Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(obj)); and [DataContract]
    public class FieldDto<TValue>
    {
        [DataMember]
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int UserRights { get; set; } = 3;

        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

Comment: It should work. Make sure you are executing maps creation code before tests

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - the code works fine. Do you have another classes with the same name `ViewModel`?

Comment: no, but it is possible that unsuccesful tests culd lock the service chanels. I got following error and my service is dead: Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.he server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn ...